# How to attach to existing screen session or create a new one and run a command?

Tags: gnu-screen

I'm using

```
screen -RdS SessionName
```

To attach to existing session if exist or create a new session and attach to it. I also have

```
screen -RdS SessionName -X stuff 'ls -l'`echo -ne '\015'`
```

To run a command in a screen session. However, I expect to be inside the screen session after this command. What is the command which does what the first does but also runs some command inside screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now the following solution completely satisfies me

```
screen -S SessionName -X stuff 'ls -l'`echo -ne '\015'`; screen -RdS SessionName
```